# Make table or database to be case insensitive

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

If I make a search for instance

"Candy" in where statement I retrieve 12 hits however if I write "candy" I retrieve 0 hits.

Is it possible to make the database or table to be case insensitive?

If yes, how?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please post your table definition and the query?

Comment: it is difficult to say that it is about 40 tables

Comment: say that about one, that would be a good start

Comment: You can make the database case-insensitive by changing its collation to one of the [_CI collations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Though this doesn't affect the collation of preexisting columns and those will need changing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your where clause case insensitive . convert left and right to the same case and then put condition . 
If I take table as mytable with attributes X and Y . where filter is on Y then 
    `select X , Y from mytable where UPPER(Y) = UPPER(@toSearch)`

or

```
`select X , Y from mytable where LOWER(Y) = LOWER(@toSearch)`
```

Comment: Would this make the query non-sargable and affect performance? I'd probably use `COLLATE` rather than use a scalar function

Comment: Yes the conversion to upper or lower may have some performance impact

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution might be to convert both the search string and the column you are searching on to lowercase using the LOWER() function in SQL Server. Something like:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM yourTable
WHERE LOWER(whatever) = LOWER(@searchString)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, maybe its easier to understand if i use your where clause ,example:

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE LOWER(whatever) = 'candy' or

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE UPPER(whatever) = 'CANDY'